# Can I extend how long a hammer lasts by throwing it into the air?

Tags: donkey-kong-94

In Donkey Kong '94 for Game Boy you can throw a hammer into the air and catch it again.  Does the time the hammer is in the air count towards the powerup running out? Or could I extend how long a hammer is active by throwing it?